# how does the gmail back to search option works

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

i'm new to asp.net..

i'm developing a web application using asp.net a jquery. i have a option to search for records using some keywords. the search option works. now i'm trying to implement an option like, when the user click a link in the search result it opens a record with a link to "Back to Search Result". similar to gmail search and back to search.

any one has any clue on where i can start. i search the web but couldn't find any way..

any advice would be very much helpful.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Gmail Email content loading through AJAX and change the URL after # so it does not post back but save to browser history and back to serch just call javascript function `history.back();` onclick event

Comment: thanks for the info. how to change the url as you said using jquery. because i'm using jquery ajax to get the result in JSON format and filling the table body. pls advice.

Comment: http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/2007/12/04/anchor-based-url-navigation-with-jquery

Comment: Thanks for the help.. i'm having an issue in showing the second page when a link in search result clicked because i need to change the url to show the second page(using query string values).